# Julia - Speed up String to Date or DateTime conversion

Tags: performance, datetime, julia

How can I speed up String to DateTime conversion in Julia? It takes long and allocates a lot of memory in the process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you convert a column or vector of strings, define the string format in a separate variable and then pass this variable as a second variable in the function Dates.DateTime.
Assuming, your strings are in a DataFrame column `df.Date`, then

replace:

```
df.DateTime = Dates.DateTime.(df.Date , "yyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS")
```

with:

```
myFormat = Dates.DateFormat("yyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS")
df.DateTime = Dates.DateTime.(df.Date , myFormat)
```

This speeds up conversion noticeably (in my case by factor 20 for a 30k element vector).

Thanks to user BioTurboNick on discourse.julialang for figuring this out. The reason is in the documentation. Essentially in the former case, julia creates a DateFormat object for each individual conversion, drastically increasing memory allocation.

````
DateTime(dt::AbstractString, format::AbstractString; locale="english") -> DateTime

  Construct a DateTime by parsing the dt date time string following the pattern given in the format string (see
  DateFormat for syntax).

  This method creates a DateFormat object each time it is called. If you are parsing many date time strings of the
  same format, consider creating a DateFormat object once and using that as the second argument instead.```
````

Comment: Alternatively: `df.DateTime = Dates.DateTime.(df.Date , dateformat"yyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS")`

Comment: This is also a valid answer to speed up formatting dates to strings with the `Dates.format()` function: `Dates.format(a, dateformat"yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS")` will be much faster than `Dates.format(a, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS")` for large `a`.